# Is this the Cancer constellation?

Tags: constellations

In this photo taken by SpaceX during one of their Falcon 9 launches, I noticed a familiar group of stars but I'm not sure of what it really is. I encircled it in red, is this group the Cancer constellation?

[image: Encircled group of stars]

[Original Image](https://flic.kr/p/rokQXY)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, that constellation is Perseus.

[image]